# BindingSource Filter on deeply nested property

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I'm having some difficulty finding the correct syntax for filtering a bindingsource. The object graph looks like this:

```
BindingList<MappingObject>.TemplateData.List<Targets>.Code
```

I need to filter on the Code property so I tried to make it look like

```
BindingSource.Filter = "Target.Code = 'Something'";
```

But that doesn't do the trick. Note that there are quite a lot of other things like `List<Target>` which all have a Code property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately we solved it by using the filtering capabilities of the XtraGrid GridView itself.

```
gridViewOrders.ActiveFilterString = string.Format("Order LIKE '%{0}%'", order.Name);
```